# Entity Framework 4 - Associations

Tags: entity-framework, associations, foreign-key-relationship

EF 4 does not support associations that are not based on foreign/primary keys.  There are lots of occasions where you need to navigate between tables using non-key fields.

For example, a medications table has:

```
medID (PK)
medGrouperID
medName
```

an ingredients table has:

```
ingredientID (PK)
ingredientName
```

and a link table has:

```
medGrouperIDID (PK)
ingredientID (PK)
```

In this case EF doesn't let me create an association between medications and the link table as neither has a foreign key for the other.

I haven't done any db design for a long time so i'm struggling to understand this restriction;  Is this following good database design or a failure of EF?

**EDIT**
The MedGrouperID allows all medications with the same ingredients, uses, instructions etc to be grouped together.  This removes the duplication of data that would exist if every medicine had its own set of records for ingredients, uses etc.

Adding a new MedGrouper table will work but this would neccessitate an additional join which can't be good for performance.

Medication

```
* MedID (PK)
* MedGrouperID (FK)
* MedName
```

MedGrouper
    * MedID (FK)
    * MedGrouperID (PK)

Ingredient

```
* IngredientID (PK)
* IngrediantName
```

MedicationIngredients (junction/join table)

```
* MedGrouperID (PK, FK)
* IngredientID (PK, FK)
```

**/EDIT**

Comment: Why doesn't your link table have FK relationships to both of the tables it's meant to be associating?  Why would you want a relationship records to exist when there is no medication or ingredient present?

Comment: My understanding is that an FK must include all fields of the PK. So the med's and ingredient tables can't have FK's with the Link table as they only have partially overlapping keys.

Comment: You're right, you would not want relationship records to exist when there is no medication or ingredient present.  I'm stuck on this basic question: "Is it normal and/or proper in ER design to join on non PK/FK fields?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this following good database design or a failure of EF?

It's not a failure of EF, it's an incorrect database design (sorry for the bluntless). That design would not work from a pure database query perspective, therefore you cannot expect EF to work it out either.

It appears you have a `*..*` between **Medications** and **Ingredients**.

Therefore you should have the following tables:

**Medication**

- MedID (PK)
- MedGrouperID
- MedName

**Ingredient**

- IngredientID (*PK*)
- IngrediantName

**MedicationIngredients** (junction/join table)

- MedID (*PK*, *FK*)
- IngredientID (*PK*, *FK*)

If you generate a model from that using Entity Framework, EF will create the two entities with the many to many association present, and the join table will not have to be mapped at all.

The thing you have to remember is relationships are based on referential integrity, which you did not have correctly setup in your current database schema.

HTH.

Comment: This will work, but using MedID in the join table rather than MedGrouperID means every medication will have it's own set of ingredients records.  This will lead to lots of duplication.  Please see update in OP.  BTW - I appeciate your bluntness ;-)

Comment: Can see your update - it's hard for us to advise as we don't really 100% understand your schema and how it works (no-one really can except you). Basically though, if you want a relationship via a navigational property - you need a FK which maps to a PK. You could always *manually* perform the joins - but it's not ideal. I would go with the MedGrouper table - one extra table is not going to hurt if it makes sense logically, especially if you join on the PK/index